# What does the red dot in the drop down review queue tab mean?

Tags: support, reviewing

Usually when I click on the review queue tab at in the top right hand corner of the site, the queues with items to review have a grey dot next to them.

Occasionally there is a red dot and I have never been able to work out what that means.

Sometimes the red dot doesn't disappear even after I have reviewed all the items in that list, maybe it is just lagging behind but it seems to linger much longer that the grey dot.

[image: Red Dot]

What does the red dot mean?

Comment: In general, "reviews are starting to pile up". I'm not sure what threshold is used though, whether it's amount of individual reviews, the time they've been there, or some combination of multiple metrics

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The red dot icon has always been a bit buggy in my opinion but this seems to be [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) from what I can find about how the indicator works. (It might have been updated but if so I missed it). According to [this main meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/305893/345161) the red dot will show for a queue if there are >=2 items in that queue at the time. That post also mentions the following caveats where number 2 is probably why this is occurring here.

> 1. People are no longer notified of review queue tasks that they can't access because of their privilege level and
> 2. People might still be notified of review tasks they have already completed if they don't get cleared after an hour

The main red dot [will then show if](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/302226/how-does-the-review-needed-indicator-work-exactly):

> 1. if any review queue has a red dot (explained below) and
> 2. if it’s been at least an hour since you clicked on the review icon.

Though note the figures in this post for individual queues N were adjusted per the first meta I linked.

So that is why you're seeing it, it is just a false positive because you've already completed the review an hour or so ago but the review itself has yet to complete.

---

For the differences on the grey and red dot then are the grey dot shows up if there are *any* reviews in the queue but lower than N and the red dot shows if the amount is higher than N.

The red dot probably lags behind and shows when it shouldn't because of the above caveats and [shouldiblamecaching.com](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/).